# Man contacts alien in post eco-disaster US. Alien wants to make deals

Tags: story-identification, aliens

Read this one within the last few years and it was fairly new then.  The setting is a post eco-disaster US, with a corporate fascism set-up.  The main character is a tech expert who the government doesn't trust, but he has skills so they keep him on a short leash.  He contacts an alien who wants to trade information for commercial purposes.

Other characters are the guy's girlfriend, who ultimately betrays him, his uncle, who is a Russian agent and a woman Chinese agent who is helping him, but for her own purposes.

Comment: How widely known are the aliens?  Why isn't everyone else trading with them?  What's special about this guy that they want to trade with _him_?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eric Nylund's *[Signal to Noise](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/700919.Signal_to_Noise)* (followed by *A Signal Shattered*) as per [Identify a book featuring Free Energy given by an alien](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/82854/identify-a-book-featuring-free-energy-given-by-an-alien?noredirect=1&lq=1).

> Jack Potter puts computer cryptography to work for the highest bidder: sometimes for private corporations, sometimes for the government. Sometimes the work is legal; if not, Jack simply raises his price. But one day, Jack discovers something cloaked in the hiss of background radiation streaming past the Earth from deep space: a message from an alien civilization. One that's eager to do business with humanity -- and its representative.
>
> Before he knows it, Jack has entered into a partnership that will open a Pandora's Box of potential profit and loss. The governments, the multinationals, and mysterious players more powerful still, all want a piece of the action -- and they're willing to kill, even wage war, to get it. Now Jack is entangled shifting web of deceit and intrigue in which no one, not even his closest friends, can be trusted. For Earth's cloak-and-dagger business practices are writ large in the heavens...and hostile takeovers are just as common across light years as they are across boardroom tables.

The girlfriend, uncle, and spies are mentioned in [the Kirkus review](https://www.kirkusreviews.com/book-reviews/eric-s-nylund/signal-to-noise-4/):

> .... Jack’s office, however, has been trashed; then his “uncle” Reno grabs him and implants a device in his head that, via ubiquitous VR “bubbles,” allows Jack to influence other people’s perceptions. Jack outsmarts Andropov DeMitri of the NSO, but his friends Isabel and Zero dose themselves with Wheeler’s enzyme, and their personalities begin to change. Panda, a Chinese agent and Reno’s rival, helps Jack evade the vengeful NSO, but the rapacious Wheeler threatens to destroy the Earth unless Jack seeks out new alien technologies for Wheeler to plunder....

What does not match was that it was published in 1998.

Comment: That's it.  Thanks.  Guess I got the time-frame wrong.

Comment: I actually read this, but didn't remember it well enough to make the connection.